# How to make simple groovy Class behave like a Grails service in groovy module?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Help required. Thanks in advance.

How to make simple groovy Class behave like a Grails service in groovy module?
Or 
How to create Grails service class in Groovy Module??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, a `Service` class features the following:

- it is a `singleton` in the app (by default, other scopes are really rare)
- it's methods are executed in transactional context by default.
- it's auto-wired

so, you can define a Groovy/Java class anywhere, add `@Transactional` into it, and define it in `Spring app-context` under `conf/spring/resources.groovy` as a singleton:

```
beans = {
  yourServicePretender YourServicePretenderClassName
}
```

Volia, you "service" is ready!

Comment: You should elaborate on the part about defining it in the Spring ApplicationContext, since this is the least obvious part and you only hand-waved over it.